# How can I remove all characters following a ' using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have IMDB data that consists of directors and actors - however, for some reason in the directors column actors names are being shown too although there is already a seperate column from that. I am trying to remove all names after the directors name but am unable to. I've tried the equations below but am not getting the results I want.

[image: the original dataset]

I've used the following equation to try to split the column into two:

```
df4[['director','actors']] = df4['director'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

However, this results in an error message:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

I've also tried to the equation below but this then results in the removal of everything but the directors name:

```
df4['director'].str.rsplit(', ').str.get(0)
```

[image: result]

hope I explained everything correctly!

Comment: I already posted an answer

Comment: If you are in control of how the data is generated, you should first try to fix whatever causes the extra information in the director column. A movie can principally have more than one director, so just taking the first element might not work in all cases. Moreover, since those cells look like stringified lists, it would be cleaner to convert them into lists first.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to assign each actor into a separate column in the destination, but there's only one `actors` column.

Use the `n=2` option to `split()` so split into two parts, so all the actors will be kept together.

```
df4[['director','actors']] = df4['director'].str.split(', ', n=2, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the actual director is always the first element in the list contained in `df4['director']`, you can write a function:

```
def extract_director(df):
    df['director_clean'] = df['director'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else None)

    return df
```

If your dataframe is `df4`,

```
df4_revised = extract_director(df4)
```

This will add a new column `director_clean` (you can rename) that gives you the director's name.